# How to prevent bootstrap from collapsing all the submenus when clicking on only one submenu?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to HTML CSS and trying to make a vertical navigation bar. My requirement is to provide sub-sub menus to sub menus in that vertical navigation bar. I did some googling and found a code and did some modificaiton to it to align it with my needs. Here is the code:

```css
#main-menu {
    background-color: #2E3039;
}

.list-group-item {
    background-color: #2E3039;
    border: none;
}

a.list-group-item {
    color: rgb(22, 21, 21);
}

a.list-group-item:hover,
a.list-group-item:focus {
    background-color: #43D5B1;
}

a.list-group-item.active,
a.list-group-item.active:hover,
a.list-group-item.active:focus {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #43D5B1;
    border: none;
}

.list-group-item:first-child,
.list-group-item:last-child {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.list-group-level1 .list-group-item {
    padding-left:30px;
}

.list-group-level2 .list-group-item {
    padding-left:60px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="side2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <!-- column1, Vertical Dropdown Menu -->
              <div id="main-menu" class="list-group">
                  <a href="#sub-menu" class="list-group-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-menu">Item 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <div class="collapse list-group-level1" id="sub-menu">
                      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 1</a>
                      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 2</a>
                      <a href="#sub-sub-menu" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 4</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 5</a>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <!-- column 2, content goes here... -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I wanted to add sub sub menus to other sub menus too... so I did some modification to my html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="side2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <!-- column1, Vertical Dropdown Menu -->
              <div id="main-menu" class="list-group">
                  <a href="#sub-menu" class="list-group-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-menu">Item 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <div class="collapse list-group-level1" id="sub-menu">
                    <a href="#sub-sub-menu" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                    </div>
                      
                      <a href="#sub-sub-menu" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                      </div>
                      <a href="#sub-sub-menu" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 4</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 5</a>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <!-- column 2, content goes here... -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But here, when I am trying to collapse sub Item 1, sub item 2 and sub item 3 are also getting collapsed.

So kindly help me with the code modification so that when I collapse sub Item 1, without collapsing other sub items.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your HTML for each of the sub-sub-menus, simply add a number to each sub-sub-menu id (e.g. sub-sub-menu#) to specify which submenu is being activated. Right now your code is telling each of the submenus to activate all at the same time because they are called the same id.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="side2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <style type="text/css">
    .column
        {
            float: right;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <!-- column1, Vertical Dropdown Menu -->
              <div id="main-menu" class="list-group">
                  <a href="#sub-menu" class="list-group-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-menu">Item 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <div class="collapse list-group-level1" id="sub-menu">
                    <a href="#sub-sub-menu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu1">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu1">
                            <div class="column">
                                Sub Sub Item 1
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu1">
                            <div class="column">
                                Sub Sub Item 2
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu1">
                            <div class="column">
                                Sub Sub Item 3
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                      
                      <a href="#sub-sub-menu2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu2">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu2">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu2">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu2">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                      </div>
                      <a href="#sub-sub-menu3" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu3">
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu3">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu3">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                          <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu3">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 4</a>
                  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 5</a>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <!-- column 2, content goes here... -->
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, Thank you very much as it worked perfectly. I would really appreciate if you could help me with one more thing. I want my sub-sub menus to appear on right side of my sub-menus. Can I modify my current code somehow to achieve this, so that sub menus will appear below the menu and sub sub menus will appear at right of sub-menus.

Comment: @noobmaster Just edited the above code snippet to add the functionality you requested. A column class is created using CSS which calls "float: right" inside of each of the <a> tags in the sub-sub-menus